# Display settings not saving after restart

Tags: windows-8, display, nvidia-graphics-card, gamma

The display settings aren't being saved, either using the regular windows control panel or the nvidia control panel, after restart the settings go back. To fix it I go into the nvidia control panel and click "Choose how color is set" and it readjusts, i don't even have to click apply. I'm using Windows 8.1 and nvidia 970m. So how do you get those settings to stay after restart?

Comment: Have you ever clicked "apply", "yes" or "accept" after the readjustment completes? If no, give it a try once!

Comment: Yeah, none work, what does work though is putting the computer into hibernate instead of sleep. Kind of a hassle though since it basically has to restart and takes longer then sleep.